# Is it safe to flush a GZIPOutputStream followed by a ByteArrayOutputStream reset?

Tags: java, gzip, java-7, flush

Here is an example code

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bufSize);
GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream1(baos);
gzos.write(...)
...
gzos.write(...)
...
// Would the content get flushed properly?
gzos.flush()
byte[] bytes =  baos.toByteArray();
// Use bytes wherever you want
...
// Would this reset things for gzos?
baos.reset()
gzos.write(...)
...
gzos.write(...)
...
bytes =  baos.toByteArray();
...
```

So, once the compressed byte array is used somewhere, I want to reset the stream. I have two concerns. I read somewhere that `GZIPOutputStream`'s flush method do not necessarily always flushes the content? Is that true still for Java 7? If that works, is calling reset of the `ByteArrayOutputStream` object enough to reset things for the `GZIPOutputStream` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read somewhere that `GZIPOutputStream`'s flush method do not necessarily always flushes the content?

It depends on what `GZIPOutputStream` constructor you use. If you create a compressor passing `true` to `boolean syncFlush`, any `flush()` call will flush both compressor and output stream, respectively. If `false`, only the output strem will flush.

> Is that true still for Java 7?

The behavior you described happened in Java 6. This `syncFlush` parameter is available since Java 7. It' in Java 8, of course.

> If that works, is calling reset of the `ByteArrayOutputStream` object enough to reset things for the `GZIPOutputStream` object?

Yes, it seems so.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!